# Sliding wrist guard iOS

Tags: ios, slider

I would like to create a sliding "view".  I want to be able to pull it from the bottom of the page.  The closest example of what I am looking for is penultimates wrist guard.  I want to be able to slide the position of this view up and down as needed.  Does anyone have any ideas on a good way to do this?  I have looked around for examples but I have not seen anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(panGestureRecognized:)];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [panRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView: YES];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [self.handleImage addGestureRecognizer: panRecognizer];


    firstX = [self.handleImage center].x;
    firstY = [self.handleImage center].y;

}


-(void)panGestureRecognized:(id)sender {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;

    if ([panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        firstX = [[panRecognizer view] center].x;
        firstY = [[panRecognizer view] center].y;
    }

    int nextPosition = firstY+translatedPoint.y;

    if(nextPosition > MIN_Y && nextPosition < MAX_Y){

        CGPoint certainPositin = CGPointMake([self.curtainView center].x,-(self.curtainView.frame.size.height)  + (nextPosition - 17));

        translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX,nextPosition);

        [[panRecognizer view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

        [self.curtainView setCenter:certainPositin];

    }


    if ([panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //Gesture ended

    }

}
```